# Please explain the use of the word Easy in this sentence

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, adjective-phrases, reduced-relative-clauses

> The tennis player, easy through the opening set against her opponent, rallied to take the final two sets for the biggest victory of her young career.

Of the following pattern, which one is implied over there?

Who went easily through the opening set or who was easy through the opening set...

Comment: It may be okay to some people, but I really don't think much of ***easy*** here, which seems *extremely* colloquial / slangy (unlike the rest of the text, so there's a real "clash" of styles). It should be the proper adverbial form ***easily***,

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious. The writing style is in journalese, and requires that the reader understand the language used for sports reporting.

The meaning needs to be inferred, if you (like me) do not immediately know what "easy" means here. But from the context, it appears to mean "taking it easy", that is, "not working hard enough", and so "easily beaten" -- because it is clear she lost that first set.